# Scan an element that disappears from screen in TOSCA

Tags: tosca

Can anyone guide me on if we can scan an error alert in TOSCA which appears on the screen only for few seconds. Is there any way to do it after the element has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If the error element is part of the web page then you can use the filter and search slider bar on the XSCAN window by sliding it towards right, it should show components  of the page with further details. The error alert component would most probably be there with the property has hidden.

Comment: I agree, the error is probably still there, but hidden.  Unless the web page reloads when the error disappears, it's probably just being hidden by some javascript after a timer.  I suggest using the mark on screen tool, click NEAR where it appears after it has disappeared, and then slide the slider to the right as mentioned above and look NEAR the selected area.. it's probably in there somewhere.  (don't forget to uncheck the un-needed "near" object after you find it.)

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer Console(F12 for Chrome)-> Settings->Debugger-> disable JavaScript. Now the element will remain on the screen for as long as you want.

Source: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/how-to-pause-javascript-and-inspect-an-element-that-quickly-disappears/